# How to import Graph from kivy.garden.graph?

Tags: python, eclipse, kivy

i can't import Graph from kivy.garden.graph and I don'n know what I'am doing wrong.

I use Linux (Ubuntu Mate 16.04) and I have installed the kivy garden package as these are described in the manual.
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.garden.html

garden list in console:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
graph
```

So i think it is successfully installed.

I try to import Graph in eclipse:

```
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph
```

But it doesn't work (unresolved import). Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if u still finding this difficult.try looking for .kivy folder in ubuntu, im quite sure you'll see a folder with the name garden and in it is another folder garden.graph. Just copy this folder into your app directory and import it from there..did this in windows and it worked out for me..so u can do `from garden.graph import Graph`but i think its better if you rename the folder to make it graph and not garden.graph and then import by doing this `from graph import Graph`

Comment: Thank you! This workaround works for me but I still don't understand why it not work with from kivy.garden.graph import Graph...

Comment: I'm glad it helped ,,I can't really tell why,,almost all the recipes from the garden suffer the same fate

Answer (score 0):

The `Graph` import from Kivy has been changed in newer versions from `from kivy.garden.graph import Graph` to `from kivy_garden.graph import Graph`.